# Trouble with Variable Name

Tags: ios, instance-variables

Apologies if this is a beginner question, but solution/correct syntax is very confusing.

Using IOS, I'm trying to find a way to create instance variable names using another outside variable.

For example, I have created custom class (e.g., NSCustomItem) and I would like to now initialize multiple separate instances using a routine within a loop, resulting in something like this:

```
NSCustomItem *item1
NSCustomItem *item2
NSCustomItem *item3
```

I'm using a loop to generate the multiple objects.  However, within the loop, I can't seem to find a way to use tags or subscripts or a naming string formula to create the object names:

I've been trying syntax ideas like

```
 (NSCustomItem *)item[i] = [[NSCustomItem alloc] init];
```

However, that's not working.

Can someone assist or provide info?  Appreciated.

Comment: If you're creating a series of objects, it would probably be better to put them into an array, rather than trying to give each one a variable name.

Comment: Please stay out of the NS- namespace.  It's not future-proof.

Answer (score 1):

Create the items and add each to an [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) like this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// then within your loop:
{
    [items addObject:[[NSCustomItem alloc] init]];
}
```

Then to access them, you can iterate through the array using [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html):

```
for (NSCustomItem *item in items) {
    // do something with item
}
```

Or check out the [NSArray class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for other ways to access the objects in the `NSMutableArray` (which is a subclass of `NSArray`).

Answer (score 0):

Never name a custom object/class with prefix like UI/NS/MF..i.e. the prefix helps to identify the framework the class belongs to, this is not a good practice to name ones own object with a prefix of an already existing framework but technically this is ok. And, in an iIOS App u can always use C like syntax, the syntax used by u is not a correct C way of declaring an array, if want to stick to C syantax u can use something like this-

```
CustomClass *aTemp[2];

//May use a for loop to populate the Array Elements
aTemp[0] = [[CustomClass alloc]init];
aTemp[1] = [[CustomClass alloc]init];    ....
```

or

```
CustomClass *aTemp[]= {[[CustomClass alloc]init],[[CustomClass alloc] init]};
```

or

**EDIT:**

```
CustomClass *aTemp[3];   

    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){ 
     CustomClass *aCustomClass = [[CustomClass alloc]init]   

     // Changes/Customizations in the aCustomClass object 

      aTemp[i]= aCustomClass;
    }
```

Also make sure that all is fine in `CustomClass`.

if u wanna write with Objective C API, answer given by @smileyborg is good.

Comment: This idea seemed the simplest, but when I try to populate the array elements through a loop, using the first solution above, I get a "variable sized object may not be initialized" error.  Any last thoughts on that?

Comment: seems that u exceeded the size that is declared while declaring the array..iterate the loop from i = 0 to i = n-1, where 'n' is the size of the array at the time of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly. But you can use an `NSMutableDictionary` to achieve something similar as,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then, every time you create an object, add it to the dictionary:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  [dict setObject:[[NSCustomItem alloc] init] 
           forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item%d", i]];//dynamically creates NSCustomItem objects with names item1, item2 etc.. till item'count'
}
```

Now when you want to use this, just use,

```
[dict valueForKey:item1];//equivalent to item1
```

or

```
[dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item%d", i]];
```

In order to access a property in `item1`(`item1.property`), use

```
[[dict valueForKey:item1] property]
```